# What L stands in seed value in spark ML

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, random-seed

I know what is the seed value and how it works but I don't know what "L" stands for in seed value in below example:

```
val splits = data.randomSplit(Array(0.6, 0.4), seed = 1234L)
val train = splits(0)
val test = splits(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L does indicate the stored number in the variable seed is of the type long.

Comment: I guessed so but was not sure. Thanks!